# Is it possible to test a lost wifi connect with xcode ui testing?

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing

I want to do some tests on how my iOS app handles lost wifi connection, using xcode ui testing. it seems that xcode ui testing only gives you control over the app, not the phone. Is there some way to do it?

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mock the response from the server API to return nil instead of status code, that way you check the behaviour of your app and how it responds to server requests.
I'm afraid you can't turn off network connectivity while your UI test is running.

Comment: Thanks thats a great idea